# Why there is a ldloc.0 just after stloc.0 in IL code?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I`m trying to learn CIL by writing small snippets of code and examining compiled assemblies. So I wrote this simple if statement:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Int32 i = Int32.Parse (Console.ReadLine());
        if (i > 0)
            Console.WriteLine ("i is greater than 0");
    }
```

And C# compiler compiled it into the following IL code:

```
.method public hidebysig static void Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 num,
        [1] bool flag)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: call string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
    L_0006: call int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::Parse(string)
    L_000b: stloc.0 
    L_000c: ldloc.0 
    L_000d: ldc.i4.0 
    L_000e: cgt 
    L_0010: ldc.i4.0 
    L_0011: ceq 
    L_0013: stloc.1 
    L_0014: ldloc.1 
    L_0015: brtrue.s L_0022
    L_0017: ldstr "i is greater than 0"
    L_001c: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    L_0021: nop 
    L_0022: ret 
}
```

As I know,`stloc` puts the topmost value from the evaluation stack into the local variable,and,if I got it right,that value isn`t popped from the stack,so why does the compiler puts the `ldloc` instruction just after it?

Comment: No, stloc *does* pop the stack.  Maybe that ldloc looks very inefficient, but output of a .NET compiler is not optimized.  Important that it works that way, you would otherwise have a pretty hard time debugging your code.  It gets optimized later, by the JIT compiler in the Release build.  A machine code optimization, not a CIL optimization.  You will not see the equivalent of stloc/ldloc back, the variable will be stored in a CPU register.

Comment: @HansPassant,but .net compiler does the optimization(by default)-try to compile something like `string s="abc";Console.WriteLine(s);` and check the outputted IL.

Comment: @IDavid - there are some optimizations that the C# compiler does perform even without the optimize flag turned on, such as constant folding.  However, in your example with optimization turned off, I indeed get an stloc.0 ldloc.0 sequence for the "abc" literal in LINQPad.  See here for what the Optimize setting does: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's only in Debug mode that you see those instructions as the compiler doesn't optimize the code so that you can debug and put breakpoints in specific parts.

If you compile this application in Release mode you see that even on IL code there's an optimization is done.

```
.method public hidebysig static void 
  Main(
    string[] args
  ) cil managed 
{
  .entrypoint
  .maxstack 8

  // [13 13 - 13 55]
  IL_0000: call         string [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadLine()
  IL_0005: call         int32 [mscorlib]System.Int32::Parse(string)

  // [14 13 - 14 23]
  IL_000a: ldc.i4.0     
  IL_000b: ble.s        IL_0017

  // [15 17 - 15 58]
  IL_000d: ldstr        "i is greater than 0"
  IL_0012: call         void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)

  // [16 9 - 16 10]
  IL_0017: ret          

} // end of method Program::Main
```